# Smallest set non-disjoint with other given sets

Tags: algorithms, sets, set-cover

Given a number of sets, what is the best algorithm to calculate the smallest set S such that S is not disjoint with any of the given sets?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem#Hitting_set_formulation ​ ​

Comment: @RickyDemer Make an answer?